# DocuSign: Went "live", now I'm getting a 404 error

Tags: docusignapi

Using the PHP API. App was working great on the developer side, now that I've gone "LIVE" and try to create/send the envelope I'm getting a 404 error.

I have:

- verified the API integration key
- changed the config settings for user id and client secret for the newly created Admin account
- had the admin account take ownership of the app and granted consent
- created new private and public keys, and verified that I'm pointing to the right files
- verified that the claim is correct, particularly the aud parameter.
- I ran get_userinfo to verify the API account id, sub user id, and production uri
- I've got my JWT token

My create/send url:

```
https://na4.docusign.net/v2.1/accounts/a...z/envelopes
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Sorry you're having this problem. Please EDIT your question to add the API response (what was the error code and message?) and the [API log](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) of your call that is failing. (Remove any private data.)

Comment: Pretty sure you didn't read the question: there is no API response or log for a 404 error.  In any event, I found the error: I omitted "restapi" from my url. The process is working now.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by the OP in a comment:

> omitted "restapi" from my url